Using sync I/O with ADL2 storage to reduce memory use in Java
We've used azure ADL2 for some time, and the amount of memory it consumes is problematic, forcing us to use awkward and lower-performing techniques.  In a discussion in this github issue, it was confirmed that the API does a ton of buffering, and suggested to me that we try the "sync" interface when it is available, and this azure page suggest that v12 of the Java SDK supports the sync API.  But I can't find out anything more about it, and the last response I got on the github issue was "thanks but we're closing this".
I'm trying to get two questions answered:

Will the "sync" API allow us to reduce memory consumption for multi-part uploads to ADL2?
If so, how do we use it? Where is the documentation or an example?

Thanks, any help appreciated.
UPDATE: Actually we already use what @Venkatesan is calling the "sync API'.  Note that we made our own "MarkableFileInputStream", which does not buffer everything in memory and yet still satisfies the markable criteria. Even then the SDK buffers nearly everything in memory. When I run the example using 8 threads and 200MB parts, you can see that the memory consumption is 1.3GB:
Creating temp file
Uploading 8 parts of size 209715200 bytes
2024-12-26T10:56:39.132 [Thread-0] MemoryLogger.logMemory:35 INFO - JVM MEMORY: used=38MB, total=1,024MB, free=985MB
2024-12-26T10:56:40.146 [Thread-0] MemoryLogger.logMemory:35 INFO - JVM MEMORY: used=16MB, total=80MB, free=63MB
2024-12-26T10:56:41.160 [Thread-0] MemoryLogger.logMemory:35 INFO - JVM MEMORY: used=1,292MB, total=4,584MB, free=3,291MB
2024-12-26T10:56:42.163 [Thread-0] MemoryLogger.logMemory:35 INFO - JVM MEMORY: used=1,304MB, total=4,584MB, free=3,279MB
...

You can download the full example from my google drive
The exact amount of memory used seems completely up to the SDK, but the amount is "a lot". If I use 16x400MB parts, the SDK uses 2.9GB. The SDK behaves like nobody would ever do more in their application than upload a single file, but we are doing a lot, moving data between files and databases, and often performing multiple transfers concurrently. The SDK is just really hungry and not predictable.  Is there any way to control the SDK memory?

Have you tried any code? If yes, please paste the code in question.

Note rick's comment in the github issue: "After an offline conversation, we've agreed that the current best option is to wait for a preview of the sync http stack and see what perf improvements that yields."
Clearly, he is talking about something other than the API we already use.   Any idea what is this "sync HTTP stack"?

I've updated with a link to a complete example.

Can't be able to access the link check the below suggestion which I shared.


"sync" API allow us to reduce memory consumption for multi-part uploads to ADL2?.

Yes, the sync API is designed to help with memory consumption by allowing more direct control over the file upload process.
You can use the below code that the append and flush methods reduce memory usage compared to loading the entire file into memory at once, the sync API in Azure SDK v12 promises a more straightforward approach to reduce overhead and buffering using Azure Java SDK.
Code:
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.*;
import com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.DataLakeStorageException;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        String fileSystemName = "test";
        String filename = "sample.csv";
        String localFilePath = "xxxx";

        DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .buildClient();

        // Get the DataLakeFileSystemClient
        DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = serviceClient.getFileSystemClient(fileSystemName);

        // Get the DataLakeFileClient for the target file path
        DataLakeFileClient fileClient = fileSystemClient.getFileClient(filename);

        // Record the start time
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        try {
            // Prepare the input stream for the file
            Path path = Paths.get(localFilePath);
            long fileSize = Files.size(path);

            // Use try-with-resources to ensure 'data' is closed automatically
            try (InputStream data = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024 * 1024];  // 32MB buffer size
                boolean overwrite = true;
                long bytesUploaded = 0;

                // Check if the file already exists
                if (!fileClient.exists()) {
                    // Initialize the file in ADLS (create if not exists)
                    fileClient.create(overwrite);
                }

                // Upload file in parts using append and commit
                while (bytesUploaded < fileSize) {
                    int bytesRead = data.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead == -1) {
                        break;  // End of file
                    }

                    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    // Append data to the file at the specified offset
                    fileClient.append(inputStream, bytesUploaded, bytesRead);

                    bytesUploaded += bytesRead;
                }

                // Commit the uploaded chunks to the file
                fileClient.flush(bytesUploaded, overwrite);

                // Record the end time
                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long duration = endTime - startTime;  //time in minutes
                System.out.println("File uploaded successfully.");
                System.out.println("Time taken to upload the file: "  +  duration  /  1_000_000_000.0  /  60  +  " minutes");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  // Handle IO exception here
            }
        } catch (DataLakeStorageException e) {
            System.err.println("Azure Data Lake error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO Exception error: " + e.getMessage());  // Catch IOException at the outer level
        }
    }
}

Output:
File uploaded successfully.
Time taken to upload the file: 4.898536025 minutes


Portal:

Version:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
    <version>12.22.0</version>
</dependency>

Reference:
Use Java to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

@Vankatesan, this is actually what we are doing now.  This doesn't avoid the buffering, because (1) we have to hold the entire part in memory, and (2) the append() eventually calls toFluxByteBuffer() which re-buffers the block.  This forces us to use smaller blocks which limits the overall blob size because of the 50K part limit.  I was hoping to find something that used a real, rewindable stream from the file system and which did not double-buffer the data.

Perhaps I need to find something that is closer to the bare-metal REST API?  Is there such a thing?

Note also, to get reasonable performance, we need to have multiple append() running in parallel, last time I checked the optimal number is between six and eight.  So the amount of memory required is part_size * parallelism * 2 (because SDK buffers it again).  If we want to load a 1TB blob, it requires 20MB parts, and so each upload consumes 320MB of memory.  We sometimes have many writes happening, so this multiplies even further, to where we are routinely needing 1GB or 2GB JVM heap.  This is a waste, because we have the data on fast local disk and don't need that kind of buffering.

thanks for your input, but I've reviewed our code, we are doing the "sync" API you mention, and we do not buffer into memory, yet the SDK does buffer.  See my update to the question.

If you need think buffer is problem here is the Rest API reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update?view=rest-storageservices-datalakestoragegen2-2019-12-12  to manage the upload process with precise control over memory.

As an alternative libraries or tools like Azure CLI, AzCopy,libraries that integrate with Azure Storage and allow better memory handling.

Also, if you figured out, please post it as answer it will be very helpful stack community.

Thanks!  Maybe the REST API is the answer.  Sometimes you just have to go bare metal :-)
